# Unable to Fetch Next batch of users using Continuation token in Python Requests

Tags: azure-devops, python-requests

Using the below code and Personal Access Token from ADO user settings I was able to fetch the List of users with the project Entitlements where it shows the users belong to which projects etc.as in the below screenshot.
[Project ref screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1BA9.png)

The issue is with the list of users, we have a total of 900 users in ADO but after running the script I was only able to see the first 50 users like below with the continuation token.
[Members with token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGOLD.png)

I am trying to use the continuation token URI in the code but getting the same 50 users. Can anyone please help me on this?

```
import requests,json
import base64

pat = 'MYPAT'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}
#fetching the JSON output using mypat
response = requests.get(
    url="https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/adient/_apis/userentitlements?select=Projects&api-version=6.1-preview.3", 
    headers=headers)
z = response.json()
ct = z.get('continuationToken','')
print(ct)
c=1
while ct!='':
    response2= requests.get(
    url="https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/adient/_apis/userentitlements?select=Projects&continuationToken={ct}&api-version=6.1-preview.3", 
    headers=headers)
    print(response2)
```

Comment: Continuation code looks something like this: "continuationToken": "+RID:~xhlRANwrWFuAt-QAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:100#ISV:2#IEO:65551#QCF:8#FPP:AgjSAwAAAAAAAGkEAAAANAAA0gMAAAAAAAACAIC31QMAAAAAAAACAHqW1gMAAAAAAAACAO6l2QMAAAA....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community, I have edited the text in my question. Can you please check and provide me a solution to resolve the issue

Comment: Script has been updated. The issue is with the continuation token to fetch the next batch of the users but i am still get the same first 50 users. Please help me on thsi